# How to perform a search on several entities with Symfony 2

Tags: search, symfony, elasticsearch

I need to perform a search on several entities with the same string then order the results.

I've heard/read a little about [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle), would this bundle be able to do it? It seems (to me) to have almost to much features for this purpose and I'm not sure it could run on a shared server (hostgator).

The other solution I can think of at the moment is doing the search "manually" (by using `join` and `union`) but I'm wondering where should I put such a function: in an existing controller, a new one, a new bundle or somewhere else? 
I'm worried as well that this manual solution could come to a cost, especially on some non-indexable fields.

Answer (score 0):

You would do custom entity repositories. Check out [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes). Basically this extends the default FindAll, FindOneBy, etc.

You would have a function like so:

```
class MyEntityRepository extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {
    public function findByCustomRule(){
        //this is mapped to your entity (automatically adds the select)
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('someAlias');  
        $queryBuilder->orderBy('...');

        //this is mapped to any entity
        $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->select('...');


        //result
        $result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
}
```

This class is defined in the doctrine mapping and lives inside the Entity folder.. Check the docs out and you should get a basic idea.